# Should a stiffener be hatched

Tags: solidworks, technical-drawing, autocad, stiffness

In my course it's preferred not to hatch ribs and webs so should I consider a stiffener like them and not hatch it or is it different and why ? [image]

Comment: How is this part being manufactured? If it's anything other than 3D printing it will be very difficult, and even then there will be issues with overhangs and/or support removal unless it's a powder-based process...

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  I think this is just an exercise for developing drawing skills.

Comment: The primary function of a drawing is to make it clear how to manufacture a part, though... Even if it's not relevant to the question, it's still a useful thought for a learner to ponder!

Comment: I managed to dig the relevant standards. BS 8888 & BS ISO 128-44 states that ribs should not be hatched ( just like your target said).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard is that The cylinder part should be hatched but not the rib.

So something like the following.

[image]